# Passing JSON to Array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I'm working on a filter in which results are filtered right away, I'm wondering if that may be the cause of the problem so I thought I would ask and see if anyone could give me a pointer on how to proceed.

```
      <script>
        var services = [
 <?php
//Variables for connecting to your database.
//These variable values come from your hosting account.
$hostname = "###";
$username = "###";
$dbname = "###";

//These variable values need to be changed by you before deploying
$password = "###";
$usertable = "###";
$url = "permalink";
$title = "Address";
$amount = "rent";
$id = "id";
$status = "Beds";
$nonprofit = "Address";

//Connecting to your database
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("He's dead Jim");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

//Fetching from your database table.
$query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $url = $row["$url"];
        $title = $row["$title"];
        $amount = $row["$amount"];
        $id = $row["$id"];
        $status = $row["$status"];
        $nonprofit = $row["$nonprofit"];

        echo '{"permalink": "';
        echo "{$url}";
        echo '",';
        echo '"title": "';
        echo "{$title}";
        echo '",';
        echo '"amount":';
        echo "{$amount}";
        echo ',';
        echo '"id": "';
        echo "{$id}";
        echo '",';
        echo '"status": "';
        echo "{$status}";
        echo '",';
        echo '"address": "';
        echo "{$address}";
        echo '",';
        echo '},';

    }
}
?>       

]
                //]]>
      </script>


  <script id="template" type="text/html">
       <a title="{{title}}" href="{{permalink}}">
         <div class="fs_box hide-for-small-down">
           <div class="fs_left">
             <span class="fs_head">{{title}}</span>
             <span class="fs_id"><img src="images/{{id}}.jpg" width="75%" height="75%" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='images/logo.png';"></span>
       <span class="fs_status">{{status}}</span>
             <span class="fs_disc">{{address}}</span>
           </div>
           <div class="fs_price">${{amount}}+</div>
           <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </script>
```

I'm expecting it to produce a bunch of results that then are filtered criteria which are elsewhere in the page.
When I try it currently just as a php code it outputs fine. However, when I try it in the php file that this should go in it produces nothing. Or does it dislike being in a script? 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why are you adding [ before the php script? You can make an array in php the use `json_encode` to encode the array to json.

Comment: @user3980820 I was putting the JSON between that or could I put the SQL to create an array then put that array in between the [ ]?

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: Additionally, is there any reason you're not using the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) method to create JSON rather than doing this completely ineffective version? That doesn't escape anything correctly and will probably produce a lot of invalid JSON output.

Comment: I'll take a look at the json_encode thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: As you're making a lot of mistakes here, you might want to spend some time picking a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that fits your style and follow their conventions and make use of the extensive community contributions that comes with them. Writing from the ground up is a messy, error-prone and frustrating exercise that's unnecessary in this day and age. Low-level PHP should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to turn an array to json and json back to an array.

Also someone will probably mention that you should not be using the mysql_* functions in PHP as they are depreciated.

Something like this:

```
 <?php
//Variables for connecting to your database.
//These variable values come from your hosting account.
$hostname = "###";
$username = "###";
$dbname = "###";

//These variable values need to be changed by you before deploying
$password = "###";
$usertable = "###";
$url = "permalink";
$title = "Address";
$amount = "rent";
$id = "id";
$status = "Beds";
$nonprofit = "Address";

//Connecting to your database
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("He's dead Jim");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

//Fetching from your database table.
$query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result) {
    $results = array()
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }

    $json =  json_encode($results);
}
?>       

]

<script>
    var services = <?php echo $json; ?>;
</script>
```

This would give you a json object to use to render in your script.

Comment: It'd be worth converting the example given in the question to a version that uses the built-in JSON function. It's way cleaner when expressed that way and has the additional benefit of actually working.

Comment: I have edited my answer to build a some json using json_encode

Answer (score -1):

What extension is the file you are saving?
If it's not .php or an extension set to render php, then you'll just have the code show up as test.
You might want to pull out the "die" statement after the db connect.  This looks like you are running php in a .js file so you probably want the entire file to write out rather than stop because you couldn't connect to the database (or at least give 0 results, maybe a warning)

Comment: It's not a JavaScript file. It's just running when rendering a `<script>` tag on a page.